# What port uses my backportpackage or bzr?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, firewall

I am working in a company what uses Ubuntu Precise on the desktops behind a proxy. The Proxy is available in /etc/environment and set as: http_proxy, https_proxy, ftp_proxy, no proxy and their uppercase versions.

So actually i have a problem with using some applications inside the Bash. If i'm using backportpackage (like backportpackage -s trusty -d precise fop) or bzr branch then just comes up a timeout.

Now i'm guessing that the programs trying to use an unsupported (from Proxies Firewall) Port. But if i can find out what port it uses, i can ask the Admins for opening the port.

May anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing a bzr branch/repository via smart-server directly (via `bzr://`, but not `bzr+ssh://` and not `http://`), the default port is 4155 according to  http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.0.18/server.htm

When using `bzr+ssh`, it will use the ssh port (22)

When using http(s), it will use 80(443).

According to http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/configuring_bazaar.html bzr should be respecting your http proxy settings, if the branches/repositories you are asking are http URLs.

The URL of the branch/repository *can* specify a specific port, and in that case the port used will be the one specified.

The manpage for backportpackage says it

> fetches a package from one distribution release or from a specified .dsc path or URL[...]

so what port it uses is dependant on the URL specified or the package details.